# Strange behavior of groovy closures referencing class field

Tags: groovy, closures

Here's a code sample:

```
class StaticTest {

  static def list = [1, 2, 3]

  void printsNothing() {
    [].with { list.each { println it } }
  }

  void printsList() {
    new Object().with { list.each { println it } }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new StaticTest().with {
      println "Expected: "
      printsList()

      println "Strange: "
      printsNothing()
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, closures in `printsNothing` and `printsList` are identical, nevertheless the result differs as `printsNothing` indeed prints nothing as if the `list` was empty. Here's the output:

```
Expected: 
1
2
3
Strange:
```

I'm using Groovy 2.2.2 with invokedynamic support enabled.

Any suggestions on whether this is a bug or I just know nothing about Groovy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was on the [user mailing list recently](http://groovy.markmail.org/thread/4y3qolvf6a4g5w7o), it's because it's looking for the property `list` in all of the elements of the empty list (and `[].list == []`).  If you change the `printsNothing` method to:

```
void printsNothing() {
    // Use this.list to get round local `with` scoping
    [].with { this.list.each { println it } }
}
```